# gcc's -fforce-mem option

Tags: gcc

Does gcc v.4.5.3 still support -fforce-mem option?  I'm trying to build the libmad MP3 decoder which uses this option.  Googling shows reference to this option, but the [online gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Index.html#Option-Index) don't show it.

Comment: So does anyone know how to get around this, as I too am trying to build libmad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [GCC 4.3 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/changes.html):

> The -fforce-mem option has been removed because it has had no effect
>   in the last few GCC releases.

Answer (score 2):

As perreal mentioned above, the -fforce-mem option no longer works.

To install libmad, use the patch, along with the instructions outlined [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/libmad.html)