# gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fforce-mem'

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I am trying to compile libmad for my Raspberry Pi on Pidora which uses the armv6hl architecture.

However when running make on the libmad source I send up with the error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-fforce-mem'
```

any ideas as to how to fix this or get round the issue that would be great!
If you need any more information just let me know.

Comment: `-fforce-mem` was removed in gcc 4.3

Comment: ok, so how would I go about sorting this, if i removed it from the make would it still build ok or can i have gcc ignore it or?

Comment: It was an optimization option; guess it can be safely removed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As commented by devnull, `-fforce-mem` was removed in gcc 4.3 (see [gcc's -fforce-mem option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015747/gccs-fforce-mem-option)).

You should either:

- Use a newer version of you library, that does no use this flag anymore
- Edit yourself the makefile/configuration files by removing every reference to this option. If the makefiles of this library are well designed, this should be easy. Since `-fforce-mem` as no effect in GCC since a long time, this should not prevent you library from running fine.

Comment: Thank you, i just moved through the makefile and deleted -fforce-mem