# SOX: installing libmad make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 & make: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: compiler-errors, makefile, redhat, sox

i hope you can help me. I want to install libmad and madplay on my System, so that SOX can decode mp3 files.

My System:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.4.76-65.111.amzn1.i686 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31003) 
(gcc version 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2) (GCC) )
#1 SMP Tue Jan 14 21:06:12 UTC 2014
```

What i´ve done:

Download:

```
[user@ip ~]$ wget ftp://ftp.mars.org/pub/mpeg/libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz
    --2014-01-25 15:50:40--  ftp://ftp.mars.org/pub/mpeg/libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz
               => ‘libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz’
    Resolving ftp.mars.org (ftp.mars.org)... 216.75.62.9, 2001:470:8398:101::1
    Connecting to ftp.mars.org (ftp.mars.org)|216.75.62.9|:21... connected.
    Logging in as anonymous ... Logged in!
    ==> SYST ... done.    ==> PWD ... done.
    ==> TYPE I ... done.  ==> CWD (1) /pub/mpeg ... done.
    ==> SIZE libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz ... 502379
    ==> PASV ... done.    ==> RETR libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz ... done.
    Length: 502379 (491K) (unauthoritative)

    100%[=======================================>] 502,379     1.29MB/s   in 0.4s

    2014-01-25 15:50:41 (1.29 MB/s) - ‘libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz’ saved [502379]
```

unpacked

```
[user@ip ~]$ gunzip libmad-0.15.1b.tar.gz
[user@ip ~]$ tar xfv libmad-0.15.1b.tar
```

./configure (I know that it is much and no idea whether it is relevant but I'll give it once for the fault i get)

```
[user@ip libmad-0.15.1b]$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for egrep... grep -E
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking how to recognise dependent libraries... pass_all
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran 77 compiler... no
checking whether  accepts -g... no
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 32768
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for ar... ar
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking if gcc static flag  works... yes
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking assert.h usability... yes
checking assert.h presence... yes
checking for assert.h... yes
checking limits.h usability... yes
checking limits.h presence... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking fcntl.h usability... yes
checking fcntl.h presence... yes
checking for fcntl.h... yes
checking errno.h usability... yes
checking errno.h presence... yes
checking for errno.h... yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking for inline... inline
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for pid_t... yes
checking for int... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking for long... yes
checking size of long... 4
checking for long long... yes
checking size of long long... 8
checking for waitpid... yes
checking for fcntl... yes
checking for pipe... yes
checking for fork... yes
checking whether to optimize for speed or for accuracy... default
checking for architecture-specific fixed-point math routines... INTEL
checking for ISO/IEC interpretation... best accepted practices
checking whether to enable profiling... no
checking whether to enable debugging... default
checking whether to enable experimental code... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating msvc++/Makefile
config.status: creating libmad.list
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

And if i want to compile it with "make" i get the following error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-7-175 libmad-0.15.1b]$ make
(sed -e '1s|.*|/*|' -e '1b' -e '$s|.*| */|' -e '$b'  \
                -e 's/^.*/ *&/' ./COPYRIGHT; echo;  \
        echo "# ifdef __cplusplus";  \
        echo 'extern "C" {';  \
        echo "# endif"; echo;  \
        if [ ".-DFPM_INTEL" != "." ]; then  \
                echo ".-DFPM_INTEL" | sed -e 's|^\.-D|# define |'; echo;  \
        fi;  \
        sed -ne 's/^# *define  *\(HAVE_.*_ASM\).*/# define \1/p'  \
                config.h; echo;  \
        sed -ne 's/^# *define  *OPT_\(SPEED\|ACCURACY\).*/# define OPT_\1/p'  \
                config.h; echo;  \
        sed -ne 's/^# *define  *\(SIZEOF_.*\)/# define \1/p'  \
                config.h; echo;  \
        for header in version.h fixed.h bit.h timer.h stream.h frame.h synth.h decoder.h; do  \
                echo;  \
                sed -n -f ./mad.h.sed ./$header;  \
        done; echo;  \
        echo "# ifdef __cplusplus";  \
        echo '}';  \
        echo "# endif") >mad.h
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/libmad-0.15.1b'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/libmad-0.15.1b'
if /bin/sh ./libtool --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -DFPM_INTEL  DASO_ZEROCHECK    -Wall -march=i486 -g -O -fforce-mem -fforce-addr -fthread-jump  -fcse-follow-jumps -fcse-skip-blocks -fexpensive-optimizations -fregmove -fsche ule-insns2 -fstrength-reduce -MT version.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/version.Tpo" -c -  version.lo version.c; \
        then mv -f ".deps/version.Tpo" ".deps/version.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/ve sion.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
mkdir .libs
 gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -DFPM_INTEL -DASO_ZEROCHECK -Wall -march=i486 -  -O -fforce-mem -fforce-addr -fthread-jumps -fcse-follow-jumps -fcse-skip-blocks -fexpensive-optimizations -fregmove -fschedule-insns2 -fstrength-reduce -MT vers on.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/version.Tpo -c version.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/version.o
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-fforce-mem'
make[2]: *** [version.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/libmad-0.15.1b'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/libmad-0.15.1b'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that code is old.  The `-fforce-mem` option hasn't been supported in GCC for many years.  See, for example, [gcc's -fforce-mem option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015747/gccs-fforce-mem-option).

If you just want to get this working I recommend you look through the `Makefile` files for references to `-fforce-mem` and simply remove that flag.  Note that every time you re-run `configure` you'll have to do it again, though, since the `Makefile` files will be recreated.

If you want to fix it "for real" you'll have to go find the places in autoconf and automake files that use it and remove it from there.

I also find it very strange that the code is forcing the architecture to be `i486` which is *really* old and will be much slower.  Unless you really do have an `i486`, which I find pretty unlikely in 2014.

Comment: Really thanks i´ve delete the line `optimize="$optimize -fforce-mem` in the file `configure` and `configure.ac` and it´s fixed my Problem.